# Failed to create the part's control treeviewer. ClassCastException

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, rcp, classcastexception

I want to create a project tree explorer in my RCP application.

This is my viewpart for tree:

```
public class ProjectExplorer extends ViewPart{  
    public static final String ID = "rcp.projectexplorer";
    public ProjectExplorer() {
    }
    private TreeViewer viewer;
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        viewer.setInput(ProjectManager.getInstance().getProjects().toArray());
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }

}
```

`ProjectManager.getInstance().getProjects().toArray()` - returns array with current projects.
Each project implements the interface `IProjectNode`.

In ContentProvider the method `Object[] getElements(Object inputElement)` I try to cast projects (`inputElement`) from `Object[]` to `IProjectNode[]`.

```
public class ViewContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return (IProjectNode[])inputElement;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        return ((IProjectNode)parentElement).getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ((IProjectNode)element).getParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
        if (((IProjectNode)element).getChildren() == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

But I have following error:"Failed to create the part's controls".

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lrcp.projects.source.IProjectNode;
at rcp.projects.ViewContentProvider.getElements(ViewContentProvider.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:699)
```

Each child in projects also implements `IProjectNode`.

How I can fix this exception? What I doing wrong?

Info about children methods:

```
public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {'
        if (((IProjectNode)element).getChildren() == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Implements for 'getChildren()' in Project class:

```
public IProjectNode[] getChildren() {
        IProjectNode[] projectNodes = {
                settingsFile,
                ldlFile,
                pythonFolder,
                outFolder
                };
        return projectNodes;
    }
```

`settingsFile, ldlFile, pythonFolder, outFolder` also implements `IProjectNode`.

Comment: Have you tried to cast `Object` to `IProjectNode` one by one instead of casting from `LObject` to `LIProjectNode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
ProjectManager.getInstance().getProjects().toArray();
```

the `toArray()` method returns an array of `Object` which you cannot cast to an array of `IProjectNode` (even though the actual contents is an array of those nodes).

Instead use:

```
ProjectManager.getInstance().getProjects().toArray(new IProjectNode[0]);
```

This form of `toArray` does return an array of `IProjectNode`

Also your `hasChildren` method is returning 'true' when the project node 'getChildren' returns null and 'false' when there are actually children. You need something like:

```
@Override
public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
    return ((IProjectNode)element).getChildren() != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It work!
But I see only root element in tree. Children don't displaying.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to formatting in comments.
I added info in main question.

Comment: You can't format in comments. This is a new question, we have resolved your original question so I suggest you mark this answer as accepted and then ask a new question.

Comment: I posted a new question. If you can help me. [Question is there.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649968/eclipse-treeviewer-children-dont-displaying)